# Wearing tallis and tefillin before z'man

Tags: tefilla, zemanim, tefilin, tallit-gadol, issur-vheter

About the time the clocks change for the season, there is always an issue at the early early minyan about when to put on tallis and tefillin.  In a few weeks of the year, that time can come 5 - 15 minutes after the minyan's regular start time.  Our rabbi instructed us that because the minyan exists for people who have to get to work at a certain hour, they may put on tallis and tefillin without a bracha and then when the time comes, they should reset their tallis and tefillin and make the appropriate blessings, then follow up with Shema.  What is the source for this heter?  Also, may retired or unemployed men join this minyan if not needed for a quorum?  Or are they barred because the heter does not apply to them?

Comment: Can you clarify what the precise procedure is? Are they putting on the Tallit and Tefillin later on in the day and just saying Shema'? Is this happening during the morning service?

Comment: @DoubleAA  Example:  Normal start time is 6:30, finish time nlt 7:00.  Tallis and tefillin one day last week was 6:42 I think.  We put on tallis and tefillin on without bracha before 6:30 making sure that the tefillin were not straight.  At 6:42 we had just finished shemoneh esrai.  The gabbi gave a klop, and we raised the tallis over our heads and said that bracha; adjusted the straps on the shel yad and said its bracha, and straightened out the shell rosh and made that bracha.  The said Shema.  Service continued from there.

Answer (score 2):

See לוח עזרת תורה in the name of Horav Henken OBM where he permits the early Minyanim to put on Talis & Tefillin after Alois. My assumption is that it is derived from the Halacha that one who walking (not riding) may put on Tefillin before Mesheyakir (see SA Siman 30:3) and as far as Talis see Siman 18:3 in Ramah that if one puts on Talis after Alois the Minhag is like the opinion that permits saying then a Beracha.